# Importing Project to Android Studio Java Errors

Tags: java, android, github

I have downloaded a project off github and opened it with Android Studio.   When I open it, my java files have a red circle as an icon, and I am unable to run the project.

I checked if my SDK wasn't directed in the project. But it is. Android Studio is connected to the SDK, with no problems.

I have also updated lots of the android updates.  Still no solution.

I found another question on stackoverflow and they said to fix this, you can go to `file - project structure`  then change the source.  I change the source, and the regular java icon will appear on the files, but all the code will have errors in them for some reason.  Everything will be an error.

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: You should extend your question by providing more details(what is the error you are getting, SS, etc)

Comment: post what error you got

Comment: make sure you use compatible  `Android Gradle Plugin` and `Gradle` with your `Android studio version`  For more information see this [link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility)